# Changing Voices In SAPI5

Tags: python, sapi, python-3.12

I want to add **more voices** in my program where I am using SAPI5.
Is there any way using which I can change its voice to of the Microsoft voices already available.

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

I want to add more voices because I want a female voice to speak instead of the default male voice which sounds very robot like.